# Truffle: Hanging on "Deploying Migrations..."

Tags: private-blockchain, truffle, contract-deployment, parity, migration

I am deploying a contract on a private testnet.  I am using Parity.

When I type:

```
$ truffle migrate --network my-network-name
```

I get a popup in the Parity interface for a password to my account.  I enter it.  (And I know it's correct because I get an error when I intentionally enter it incorrectly.)

The popup goes away, but:

a) no ETH has been removed from the account

b) the console does not change.  It still shows:

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js   
   Deploying Migrations...
```

...and it hangs there for at least 10 minutes.

Has anyone encountered this before?

EDIT: I have also unlocked an account on the command line as described here:
[Truffle migration stuck](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15501/truffle-migration-stuck/15566#15566)  The result is the same: the migration hangs.

I am sure I have unlocked the correct account because "web3.eth.accounts[0]" from the web3 console (see [here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Basic-Usage#javascript-console))returns the account I am unlocking.

Comment: did you check if mining is running? If yes then you can try restarting your geth node.

Comment: I have no mining running.  It's a VPS.  The account is funded as part of the chain specification.  Also I am running Parity, note Geth.

Answer (score 1):

What I got with Parity was a screen showing up on a page served by a service on another port with a button to *confirm* the transaction. If you're sending a few different transactions in the course of your deployment, you get a number of these authorization requests showing up, and you have to click all of them.

The workaround is to run Parity with the deploy account unlocked. See this answer for how to do that:
[Truffle migration stuck](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15501/truffle-migration-stuck/15566#15566)

Comment: Edmund, I have done that but it also doesn't work.  ie - it still hangs.  BUT maybe I am using the wrong "deploy account?"  How do I specify which account is the correct "deploy account?"

Comment: If you connect to the node with the console and do `web3.eth.accounts[0]` that should be the account truffle is using to deploy your contracts.

Comment: Edmund, I have edited my OP again.

Answer (score 1):

Trick is mining, please initiate the mining by executing
`miner.start()`.

Comment: This did it for me! Do not stop mining while you deploy your contracts.